# Does non-uniform indexing into a sampler2DArray ever cause undefined behavior?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, texture-mapping, vulkan

I'm interested in selecting textures dynamically within a Vulkan shader (though maybe this question applies equally to OpenGL).  I am presently emerging from a long process of being confused by the distinction between a single `sampler2DArray` and an array of `sampler2D` objects.  The latter, it seems, cannot be dynamically (let alone non-uniformly) indexed unless certain features or extensions are reported by the graphics library to be supported.

But is it allowed to choose a layer from a `sampler2DArray` in a dynamic, non-uniform way (that is, using completely arbitrary indices), on all hardware, regardless of reported feature support or extension presence?  I think I am reading in some places that it is, but this is so confusing that I'd like to be told as explicitly as possible.

Comment: So much for "as explicitly as possible".  Anyway I gather the answer is "no, assuming the index is within the bounds of the array".  Excellent!

Comment: Read comments in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/8kthkc/array_of_sampler2d_variable_index_fails_program/).